# How to use WebDeploy with ASP.Net core

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, msdeploy, webdeploy

We have an Update-Program that publishes automatically WebDeploy-Packages to IIS-Servers. This Program works fine with MVC 5 - Applications but not with .Net Core Applications. We Use the Microsoft.Web.Deployment - API and my publish method looks like this:

```
private void UpdateIIS(DTOs.ApplicationConfiguration.ApplicationServer applicationServer, DTOs.Update.Update update) {
    // SSL-Zertifikatsfehler ignorieren
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(
        (object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; });
    var sourceBaseOptions = new DeploymentBaseOptions();
    var destBaseOptions = new DeploymentBaseOptions() {
        ComputerName = string.Format("https://{0}:{1}/msdeploy.axd?site={2}", applicationServer.Adresse, applicationServer.MSDeployPort, applicationServer.SiteName),
        UserName = applicationServer.User,
        Password = applicationServer.Passwort,
        AuthenticationType = "Basic"
    };
    string updatePackage = Directory.GetFiles(update.UpdateDirectory, "*.zip").FirstOrDefault();
    if (!File.Exists(updatePackage)) {
        throw new Exception("Update-Paketdatei nicht gefunden");
    }
    using (var deploymentObject = DeploymentManager.CreateObject(
        DeploymentWellKnownProvider.Package,
        updatePackage,
        sourceBaseOptions)
    ) {
        if (deploymentObject.SyncParameters.Count > 0) {
            deploymentObject
            .SyncParameters
            .Single(p => p.Name == "IIS Web Application Name")
            .Value = applicationServer.SiteName;
        }


        var syncOptions = new DeploymentSyncOptions();
        var changes = deploymentObject.SyncTo(
            DeploymentWellKnownProvider.Auto,
            "",
            destBaseOptions,
            syncOptions
        );
    }
}
```

I get no errors, but the Website doesn't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use WebDeploy with ASP.NET Core.  The key is to use the PackagePublish target and a package publish profile:

```
D:\GitHub\AcmeApp.NET\src\AcmeApp.NET.Web>"c:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild" /t:PackagePublish /p:PublishProfile=Package
```

http://www.dotnetcatch.com/2016/09/20/webdeploy-packaging-with-asp-net-core/

Comment: For whatever reason, `/t:PackagePublish` always returns with the error `The target "PackagePublish" does not exist in the project` when I try that out. Is this still the way to go?

Comment: What version of Core are you using?

Comment: Looking like 1.1.1 (installed it very recently so you can assume the latest version).

Comment: I couldn't get this to work, I get the following error: `error MSB4041: The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML namespace. If the project is authored in the MSBuild 2003 format, please add xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" to the <Project> element. If the project has been authored in the old 1.0 or 1.2 format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format.`.  I'm at a total loss as  to how to deploy a .NET Core app!

Comment: Can you share a repro on Github?

Comment: @chief7 Turns out I was using the wrong version of MSBuild.  According to this: https://github.com/aspnet/websdk/issues/166#issuecomment-289235351, WebDeploy doesn't support .NET Core, although the work around using MSBuild 15 doens't work for me either.  Basically we're having to wait for `dotnet publish` to support publish profiles before we can deploy our app.

Comment: PackagePublish doesnt work any more with .NET Core, you should use WebPublishMethod: `"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=package` source: https://www.dotnetcatch.com/2018/06/13/webdeploy-packaging-with-asp-net-core-2-0-includes-function-apps/

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `dotnet publish` to do this directly from your project without explicitly invoking MSDeploy.

```
$uid='username'
$pswd='password'
dotnet publish /p:PublishProfile=Properties/PublishProfiles/Live.pubxml /p:Username=$uid /p:Password=$pswd -c Release
```